# Configure riak-java-client to use https proxy

Tags: java, riak, http-proxy

I am trying to connect to Riak server from behind https proxy using [riak java client](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client) version 2.1.1.

Setting `-Dhttps.proxyHost` and `-Dhttps.proxyPort` does not help.

Providing `io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap` instance to node builder also does not seem to help, because there is no way to specify `ChannelPipeline` to use proxy `ChannelHandler` because `RiakChannelInitializer` overrides everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Riak Java client does not support the HTTP protocol. Please see [the docs](https://github.com/basho/riak-java-client/wiki/RiakClient-%26-Cluster-Node-Builders-%28v2.0%29) for more information on connecting over TCP sockets.

Comment: yes, although the docs don't say explicitly that HTTP is not supported they mention default protobuf listener port in the examples. I guess should be fairly easy to write rest client with async-http-client. Thanks!